# LAG function with sequential calculus

Tags: sql, postgresql, lag, sequential

I come to you today because I'm struggling with a query that involve the LAG function (FYI, I am using PostgreSQL).
I have a table that contains the quantities of a product sold by country to another one on a monthly basis. The table is defined like this:

```
create table market_research.test_tonnage(
    origin text, -- Origin country
    desti text, -- Destination country
    yr int, -- Year
    mt int, -- Month
    q numeric -- quantity sold (always > 0)
)
```

Here is the content:

| origin | desti | yr | mt | q |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| toto | coucou | 2019 | 1 | 1.4 |
| toto | coucou | 2019 | 2 | 2.5 |
| toto | coucou | 2019 | 3 | 1.2 |
| tata | yoyo | 2018 | 11 | 5.4 |
| tata | yoyo | 2018 | 12 | 5.5 |
| tata | yoyo | 2019 | 1 | 5.2 |

I am trying to create a view that will add 2 calculated fields as following:

- beginning_stock : Initial value of 0, then beginning_stock = ending_stock of the previous month
- ending_stock : ending_stock = beginning_stock - q

| origin | desti | yr | mt | q | beginning_stock | ending_stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| toto | coucou | 2019 | 1 | 1.4 | 0 | -1.4 |
| toto | coucou | 2019 | 2 | 2.5 | -1.4 | -3.9 |
| toto | coucou | 2019 | 3 | 1.2 | -3.9 | -5.1 |
| tata | yoyo | 2018 | 11 | 5.4 | 0 | -5.4 |
| tata | yoyo | 2018 | 12 | 5.5 | -5.4 | -10.9 |
| tata | yoyo | 2019 | 1 | 5.2 | -10.9 | -16.1 |

I have tried many queries using the LAG function but I think that the problem comes from the sequentiality of the calculus over time. Here is an example of my attempt:

```
select origin,
       desti,
       yr,
       mt,
       q,
       COALESCE(lag(ending_stock, 1) over (partition by origin order by yr, mt), 0) beginning_stock,
       beginning_stock - q ending_stock    
 from market_research.test_tonnage
```

Thank you for your help!
Max

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (no images.) Also show us your current query attempt. I.e. [mcve].

Comment: You want a sum not a lag.

Comment: @jarlh I've added information, hope it helps !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a cumulative `SUM()` function instead of `LAG()`:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=892596e5d88ea599fa587312dfbb34e1)

```
SELECT
    *,
    SUM(-q) OVER (PARTITION BY origin ORDER BY yr, mt) + q as beginning, -- 2
    SUM(-q) OVER (PARTITION BY origin ORDER BY yr, mt) as ending         -- 1
FROM my_table
```

1. Sum all quantities (because you want negative values, you can make the values negative before, of course) until the current gives you current total (`ending`)
2. Same operation without the current value (add `q`  again, because the `SUM()` subtracted it already) gives the `beginning`.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, that' s a smart solution! :-)